# Three.js Add variable to object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Three.js I want to create an object and then add a variable to it. I'm sure it's simple but I can't seem to do it, nor work out how to do it.

For example, I create a cube, and I want it to store a variable "beenHit" that can then be accessed in a Raycast.intersectObjects later on.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var newColor = new THREE.Color("rgb(12%, 6%, 0%)");
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: newColor } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );
var cube.beenHit = false;
```

Is clearly wrong, but I've tried different ways and searched quite a bit, but my feeble brain cannot compute. Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the object `THREE.Object3D.userData`.

```
cube.userData.beenHit = false;
```

But

```
cube.beenHit = false;
```

without <strike>`var`</strike>

Can do the trick too. Remember that `THREE.Object3D` are nothing more than JavaScript objects, you can store anything you want as long as you don't override *Three.js* properties.

**Edit**

As [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389194/martin) pointed out, you should always use `userData` or you might encounter **compatibility issues** in the future.

Comment: cube.userData.beenHit is a correct, if you use cube.something = foo, you can have compatibility problems in future.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.